# Source of extra margin in my html page?

Tags: html, css

The link below shows a page which has an issue. The right pane shows a login piece. There's an empty gap between the name field and the 'Member Login' part. Firebug indicates the gap is caused by a a bottom-margin (16.6px) on the div containing 'Member Login' text.
Which CSS element is causing the margin? I can't find it.

http://demo.host22.com/

Comment: I get this page "Website Under Review" when I click the above link.

Comment: This is weird. I get the proper page when I test two different machines on different networks.

Comment: I think the hoster took it offline for review. it should be up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your H2 element still has a margin around it. Under your CSS rule for #right H2.mem you just need to say 'margin: 0;' and you should have the two elements touch each other.

Comment: The H2 doesn't have a margin specified for it. Is there an easy way to find the real source for the margin? Like which parent is causing it? Or for a computed css value, how it is computed from the constituents?

Comment: We're talking about the default margin here. All HTML elements will have some type of margin and padding to them as default. By zeroing the margin out, you're getting rid of the defaults for all browsers.

Comment: I thought the site had a css reset plugged in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cant find 'Member login' (only see a member area link). Cant find name field? Hope you do not want me to register.

Comment: The box has a black background. The whole page is static. It's a template. No buttons work.